# Need assistance with uncanny, reproducible MySQL ERROR 1452 (23000) Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: mysql, hibernate, macos, foreign-key-relationship

MySQL select version() is 5.5.9 on Mac OS/X 10.6

**Question**

When I execute the sql script below, I encounter a very perplexing foreign key constraint error. It seems as though it should not throw this error.  Moreover, I know that others have attempted to follow the steps but are unable to repro (see: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,415350,415350#msg-415350)

Can anyone spot what it is we're doing wrong?

**To reproduce:**

1. create database constraint_test;
2. create the constraint_test.sql file and paste the sql below.
3. from the cmd line execute "mysql constraint_test < constraint_test.sql" (or in my sql execute "source tmp/constraint_test.sql"

**Expected result:** row persisted to client, insured and beneficiary tables.

**Actual result:** As you'll see, the foreign key constraint error we consistently receive is similar to:

"ERROR 1452 (23000) at line 55: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`constraint_test`.`beneficiary`, CONSTRAINT `FK41BADEC55CE3480` FOREIGN KEY (`insured_id`) REFERENCES `Insured` (`insured_id`))"

However, there is definitely an insured_id in the parent table Insured.

Please help if you can!

**constraint_test.sql contents:**

```
create table Beneficiary ( 
beneficiary_id bigint not null, 
district varchar(255), 
serviceUnit varchar(255), 
insuredNo integer, 
beneficiaryIndex integer, 
relationship varchar(255), 
percentage double precision, 
fullName varchar(255), 
lastUpdatedDate datetime, 
insured_id bigint, 
contractNo varchar(255), 
primary key (beneficiary_id) 
); 

create table Client ( 
client_id bigint not null, 
firstName varchar(255), 
lastName varchar(255), 
email varchar(255), 
initial varchar(255), 
birthDate datetime, 
district varchar(255), 
serviceUnit varchar(255), 
genderType varchar(255), 
externalId varchar(255), 
externalTempId varchar(255), 
taxationProvince varchar(255), 
children varchar(255), 
manufacturerClientNumber varchar(255), 
primary key (client_id) 
); 

create table Insured ( 
insured_id bigint not null, 
client_id bigint not null, 
insuredNo integer, 
primary key (insured_id) 
); 

alter table Beneficiary 
add index FK41BADEC55CE3480 (insured_id), 
add constraint FK41BADEC55CE3480 
foreign key (insured_id) 
references Insured (insured_id); 

alter table Insured 
add index FKD7E770CAC207FE14 (client_id), 
add constraint FKD7E770CAC207FE14 
foreign key (client_id) 
references Client (client_id); 

insert into Client (client_id) values (1); 
insert into Insured (insured_id, client_id ) values (1,1); 
insert into Beneficiary (beneficiary_id, insured_id) values (1,1);
```

Comment: output of show engine innodb status?

Comment: okay, some progress at least here.  even after adding the "not null" to Beneficiary.insured's data type we were able to reproduce the error.  However, our show engine innodb output contains the following under latest foreign key errors:

"But the parent table `constraint_test`.`Insured`
or its .ibd file does not currently exist!"

The table Insured definitely exists.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I wrestled with this exact problem for most of today before stumbling onto this error.  If you're using Hibernate, you can fix this problem by using the ImprovedNamingStrategy class to name the tables rather than the default.

Answer (score 0):

Your datatypes don't match exactly:
Beneficiary.insured_id is `bigint`, whilst Insured.insured_id `bigint not null`

Innodb is very very touchy about these, make sure that your FKs columns definitions are exactly the same in both tables, including nullability.

Comment: was excited to try your response bc it seemed so obvious.  unfortunately, no luck even when the data types matched exactly.  any other suggestions?

Comment: Looks like this could be related: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=18800 - you could try changing the default character set from UTF8 to latin1 to see if this is your issue.

Comment: thanks for the point in the right direction @ggiroux!!  The latin1 didn't help unfortunately.  However,  I did rename the tables all to lowercase and that did make a difference.  A quick search indicates I should maybe setting lower_case_table_names = 1 since I am using InnoDB.  On Mac OS/X it is 2 by default (and I failed to mention I'm using a new box which may be why it isn't working locally).  That make sense you think?  Thx for your help again ggiroux!

Comment: Here's the link to the man where I found the info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names

Comment: oh great it looks like you nailed it!